# PHP loop is out of order

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, while-loop

In my PHP I am having problems with a loop.  It should be writing from lower to higher but it is writing from higher to lower. Here is my code extremely cut down.

Variables equal these at first.

```
$high = 5
$number = 10
```

Loop

```
for ($i=$high; $i<=$number; $i++)
  {

  if (file_exists("blog/" . $i . ".txt")) {
    echo "The file $i.txt exists <br />";
}else{
    echo "This file $i.txt doesnt exist <br />";
}

  }
```

The output goes like this

```
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

But shouldn't it go like this? This is what I need.

```
10
9
8
7
6
5
```

Comment: The `for` reads: start at `$i=$high`, and while `$i<=$number` is true, execute the body and `$i++`.

Comment: Your script is OK doing what you asked it to do... from $high to $number which displays 5 to 10. You will need to reverse this

Comment: so why -2? im just wondering I spent hours trying to figure this out as it is??

Comment: I know exactly how to fix it now but I don't deserve down votes?

Comment: Not one of the downvoters, but it was likely because this is a very trivial misunderstanding of how a `for` loop works.

Comment: I was one of the downvoters. One reason is what [@jprofitt just said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865799/php-loop-is-out-of-order#comment14156617_10865799). Second is because you should be able tell that it adds stuff when using the add (`+`) sign. Third because it is a RTFM question (combo with #1).

Comment: @SpencerMay: That are only points, don't care about. You get normally downvotes on questions when others think you didn't do your homework and stuff, like looking up the manual and so on.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa Um sir I hate to break it to you but I know exactly what my code is doing, the variable was set to 5 and would add one everytime the loop happened until it reached 10, so it should have written 5 then 6 then 7 then 8 and so on. Im not stupid I know that + means to add.

Comment: @SpencerMay It's just some points. Get over it. Also note that there were three people thinking the same so that too should tell you something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should decrement your $i and change stop condition.

```
$heigh = 10;
$number = 5;

     for ($i=$high; $i>=$number; $i--) {

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The opposite order is needed

```
$i=$number; $i>=$high ; $i--
```

Answer (score 2):

The order is correct for how you have written it.

try

```
for ($i=$number; $i>=$high; $i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the for statement to something like this

```
for ($i=$number; $i>=$high; $i--)
```